# How can I automount a CIFS share in /home?

Tags: 18.04, automount, nfs, domain-server

I have configured the machine using realmd and SSSD for domain join. When a user logs in it auto creates the home directory for that user in the local disk.

I checked many articles but I am still not sure of best practice for the VDI environment.

What I am trying to do here is make the `/home/%D/%U` saved in cifs share; in other words I want to redirect all the home directories to cifs share for all the users.

How exactly can I achieve this?

Comment: Any pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.

You can directly mount 10.x.x.212:/home to /home in Ubuntu 18.04 and when the home directories created through SSSD...it auto shares with NFS.

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently broken because of snap and apparmor not working nicely in Ubuntu 22.04.